# Fabric integration to Android Studio

Tags: android, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I have integrated fabric(Crashlytics) to android studio 1.2.2 and have set up the build.gradle file according to the doc provided by Twitter Fabric. Application builds fine but when i run it, i see the following error on the line where i initialize fabric with

```
Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());

E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'com.crashlytics.android.beta.Beta', referenced from method com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics.<init>.
```

Was wondering if any one came across this issue when integrating Fabric to android app?

Comment: show please your build.gradle (part with crashlytics settings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe Fabric is now on version 2.4.0. Make sure your build.gradle file is using that version. You now initialize it like so:

```
CrashlyticsCore core = new CrashlyticsCore.Builder().disabled(BuildConfig.DEBUG).build();
Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics.Builder().core(core).build());
```

You can remove the ".disabled(BuildConfig.DEBUG)" if you want to. That just disables the plugin if you're in debug mode.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried this initialization and now i get a similar error which says `07-09 10:30:55.194    7838-7838/org.kp.m.beta E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'com.crashlytics.android.beta.Beta', referenced from method com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics$Builder.build`

Comment: I installed fabric plugin 2.4.0 and that added the necessary dependencies in my build.gradle file as follows: `buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

apply plugin: 'io.fabric' 

dependencies {compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.4.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;

    }`

Comment: Thanks for the info! I have the exact same build.gradle file setup. I still see the issue :( . I also have the api key declared in the manifest file. All i did was take the latest fabric plugin and install as per the doc.  May be i should try just the stand alone crashlytics version. But i am not sure if they are supporting it anymore.

Comment: I'm not sure then. I also have my API key in the manifest file. If you try creating a new project does it still not work?